# Vertical align a position fixed div with fluid height

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a div with these properties:

```
.tourcontainer {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    padding:200px;
    z-index:20;
    color:white;
}
```

I have the challenge, that the content of the div is fluid, so i don't know how to make it vertical align regardless of the height of the div.

Comment: This issue have been discussed several times on Stackoverflow, However have a look at: http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

```
.div{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```